# Material Design ToolBar with ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, android-toolbar

I am replacing the `ActionBar` and integrating the Material Design `ToolBar` within my app. One of my activity's extends `ListActivity`.

In the `onCreate()` method, whenever I try to add the `ToolBar`, the `setSupportActionBar()` method is producing an error saying it cannot be resolved.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_recipients);

        // Attaching the toolbar layout to the toolbar object
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // get the default list view associated with this activity
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  // we can now check and uncheck multiple friends

        // get the array of LatLng points passed in from the map intent
        markerPoints = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("markerPoints");
    }
```

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: What´s the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

You wrote that your activity extends `ListActivity` but sadly `ListActivity` doesn't implement `setSupportActionBar`.  You have to base your activity on `AppCompatActivity`.

You'll say "but hey, but I really need `ListActivity` as I've `ListView` in my Activity" -- consider using `RecyclerView` as well.  I'd say that `ListView` is a dead end now -- one should port code to `RecyclerViews`

And as a help, two sample projects showing all new features of Material Design

- https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp
- https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: thank-you @pelotasplus ... I will try to replace the ListView with a RecyclerView and see how it goes...